# How to return a value in a void for only one void

Tags: c, return, void

How do I return a value in an int(24) but for a specific void it will return 25 (So it actually returns 24, but in a specific void called "main" it will return 25) Here's my code.

```
int returnnum(){
    return 24;
}
void main(void){
    printf(returnnum() + 5); /*It should result 30*/
}
void notluckytoday(void) {
    printf(returnnum() + 5); /*But here it should result 29*/
}
```

Comment: Why should the result be different if the code is exactly the same (appart from the naming)?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for rand()?

Answer (score 1):

You can't depend on the calling function. What you can do, however, is pass an argument to the function that governs its behavior somehow. E.g.:

```
int returnnum(int toadd) {
    return 24 + toadd;
}
void main(void){
    printf("%d\n", returnnum(1) + 5);
}
void notluckytoday(void) {
    printf("%d\n", returnnum(0) + 5);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, It was a pretty stupid question. I needed to think before asking!

Comment: `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`